# Powershell Match Statement from list of Files

Tags: powershell

I am searching through a directory looking for files that only contain the number `0`.

I have used the code:

```
$fileList = Select-String -Path c:\cnt\*.txt -pattern "0"
```

And it outputs a list, such as:

```
C:\cnt\itm123.txt:1:0
c:\cnt\itm1234.txt:1:0
c:\cnt\itm123456.txt:1:0
```

I need to only extract the `itm###` but the total numbers in the filename can range from 3-6.

Using the example above I need a list that looks like:

```
itm123
itm1234
itm123456
```

Once I get that I will run each through a SQL query, but I am not worried about that part.

Comment: To clarify, you only need the file name, without the path? For e.g itm1234.txt:1:0

Comment: Do the files that you are looking for consist of a single "0" character? What about the other files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Select-String](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113388) cmdlet returns a list of  `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` objects. If you call the [Get-Member](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113322) cmdlet with the parameter `-MemberType Properties` you will get a list of all exposed properties:

```
Name       MemberType Definition                                                       
----       ---------- ----------                                                       
Context    Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename   Property   string Filename {get;}                                           
IgnoreCase Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}                                       
Line       Property   string Line {get;set;}                                           
LineNumber Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}                                        
Matches    Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}        
Path       Property   string Path {get;set;}                                           
Pattern    Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
```

In this case, you are looking for the `Filename` property. So if you execute

```
Select-String -Path c:\cnt\*.txt -pattern "0" | select FileName
```

you will get all filenames:

```
itm123.txt
itm1234.txt
itm123456.txt
```

Now all you have to do is to remove the file extension which can be done using the `.NET` method [GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Select-String -Path c:\cnt\*.txt -pattern "0" | 
    ForEach-Object { [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.FileName)}
```

**Output**:

```
itm123
itm1234
itm123456
```